msys mingw64 compiled library: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
I compiled native library using msys with compile flags -s -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-unwind-tables -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fstack-protector -fno-math-errno -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias and also added target_link_libraries(myapp -static) in CMake
Everything works fine, but when i tried to run my native library on Windows Server 2019 Standard X64, i'm getting error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\user\Desktop\lib\native.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
        at com.basic.app.SyntheticProtectedApplication.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\user\Desktop\lib\native.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2394)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
        at com.basic.app.API$NativeBridge.<clinit>(API.java:170)
        at com.basic.app.API.initialize(API.java:59)
        ... 1 more

I tried to check if i don't have any dynamic libraries linked


But it seems like i don't have any external library, Dependencies app shows all modules are loaded correctly. My GCC version:
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

What may be the problem here? I want my library to be compatibile with all Windows versions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78982617/4788546 might help.

The problem was not related with JNI, it even returns fake error code.
I used WinDbg to check what exactly may be a problem, and i found that
(1868.1690): Illegal instruction - code c000001d (first chance)
(1868.1690): Illegal instruction - code c000001d (!!! second chance !!!)
native!LoginLicenseKey+0x35484:
00007ffa48ad4834 c4c1f96ece      vmovq   xmm1,r14

I found that it's related with cpu instructions, i changed cpu from kvm64 to host and problem is gone

But it's not universal solution, i found better. It's enough to disable modern cpu instructions in gcc:
-mno-avx -msse3 -march=core2

